# What messages TEdit in delphi needs to answer in order for Windows Text Suggestions to work

Tags: delphi-10.4-sydney

When you create an new VCL form with one and put one TEdit and one TComboBox in it windows text suggestions works only with TComboBox. I guess this is because the Edit part of the combobox is a windows edit. I cannot seem to find anywhere how to make the VCL's edit behave the same way. Is there some IME messages I need to handle in a certain way or anything else?

Comment: These suggestions in `TComboBox` are the values in the combo's list? That's easy for the system to offer them as suggestions. But for a standalone edit control, where do you expect it to find candidates to suggest for you?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is usually named autocomepletion.
TEdit doesn't support this out of the box (Not that I am aware of).
But there are several solutions floating around on the internet.

Not a direct solution, but have look at the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137859/tedit-with-autocomplete-suggestion-list) and also this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339048/firemonkey-edit-combo-autocomplete-autosuggest-while-typing).

There is source code available for several solutions, you'll find it with this [search on Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=delphi%20tedit%20autocompletion).

Comment: if you feel that this question is asking something that has already been asked, then the best approach is to close it as a duplicate. That allows the questions to be linked which is beneficial for future visitors. Remembering that the primary goal, and use, for topics here is not by the person asking, but for people visiting in the future who are asking the same question.

Comment: I am asking exactly what I meant. To be precise windows have named the option 'Show text suggestions as I type on the software keyboard'. I have gone trough the answers you've suggested and they all explain how to implement autocompletion with my own database of words. What I need is to make my controls work with the built in windows functionality.